# Can the as keyword replace try/catch block?

Tags: c#

If you are doing something trivial that if succeeds its a bonus but can fail and you don't want to use a try/catch for overhead costs, can the `as` keyword and test for null semantically replace the try/catch?

```
var item = new CreateItem(filename) as Item;
if (item != null) {
    ItemList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: What exceptions do you expect being thrown?

Comment: I would say you would get the same/intended behaviour, so go for it.

Comment: I think he is looking for InvalidCastException, if he didn't use the "as" keyword

Comment: I thought that the as keyword would ignore any exceptions. In this example, maybe a filenotfound exception.

Comment: @GerardSexton `FileNotFoundException` will still be thrown if you do not try catch it in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what error you're trying to catch. I would consider using the same pattern as `int.TryParse` etc - I *wouldn't* use `as` in this situation, personally:

```
Item item;
if (TryCreateItem(filename, out item))
{
    // Use it
}
else
{
    // Don't
}
```

Or you *could* just make `TryCreateItem` return null if it fails:

```
Item item = TryCreateItem();
if (item != null)
{
}
```

`as` is really used for situations where the execution time type of an evaluated expression *may* be of the desired type, but it *may* be of a different type.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified my understanding of the correct use of the as keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Not in this case, no. Either the constructor will succeed, and you'll get a `CreateItem` created successfully, or an exception will be thrown if something goes wrong, and you will have to handle it in a try/catch block.

If you really don't want to use an exception, create an `Initialize` method:

```
CreateItem item = new CreateItem(filename);    // this throws no exceptions
bool initialized = item.Initialize();          // this returns true if intialize succeeded, false if something went wrong
if (initialized) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your constructor can't throw any other exceptions then yes.

Answer (score 1):

`try` is quite efficient in .NET (it produces more overhead if there's actually an exception thrown and the `catch` block comes into play), so you shouldn't worry too much about `try` blocks.

Also, the `as` keywords only avoids exceptions when casting by returning `null` if the cast would fail. If `CreateItem` throws an exception, you would still need to handle it. So in your case, the `as` keyword doesn't really replace try/catch.
The `as` keyword does *not* replace exception handling. It's just for casting that might fail.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular problem of null-pointer exception on cast sure it can. But if CreateItem throws an exception your application will die an untimely death.

Comment: It's called a `NullReferenceException` in c# :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. The `as` keyword has a distinct meaning, and while it's a good alternative to doing explicit casts and catching exceptions, it's not a good general-purpose flow control mechanism.

Instead of using `as`, simply have your method return null and check for it. You don't need the fake-casting for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` keyword when the conversion is allowed to fail. Otherwise you need to use `(Item)new CreateItem(filename)`.

So you can replace a try/catch with the as/null check but remember that there are more types of exceptions then the `NullReferenceException`. Maybe you still want to catch for other exception types.

Answer (score 0):

If your block used to catch InvalidCastException in the case CreateItem did not return an Item instance, you can replace it with your 'as' code for the same purpose.

If your block used to catch other exceptions as well then the answer is no.